# Custom width on popovers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, popover, react-bootstrap

The content inside my [popover](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers) is too narrow, how do I apply a custom width to it?

Since the button is near the right of the page `style={{width:'300px'}}` in my popover component extends it past the width of the page and blocks content.

Ideally I'm looking for a wide popover spawned below a button located at the right side, but completely contained on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The component has a max-width setting.  Override it by adding {maxWidth: 'none'} to your style object.